# Year changing dynamically depending on the current year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if it's possible to have a query where the year of a date changes dynamically depending on the current year, with the month and the day remaining the same.
For example, I would like the query to get the rows for which the date is between 2017-09-15 and 2018-03-15, if the current year is 2017.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If 2012+, you can use datefromparts()

**Example**

```
Select DateR1 = DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),9,15)
      ,DateR2 = DateAdd(MONTH,6,DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),9,15))
```

**Returns**

```
DateR1        DateR2
2017-09-15    2018-03-15
```

So in a WHERE

```
...
Where DateCol between DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),9,15)
                  and DateAdd(MONTH,6,DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),9,15))
```